# Wordpress display post count for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, elementor

I have a custom post type created and a taxonomy with CPT plugin. Using Elementor I created an archive page to show the posts from the taxonomies created.

I would like a shortcode to dynamically display the number of posts from each taxonomy.

For example I have post type AI-Tools with taxonomy best-ai-tools and over 30 categories under this taxonomy.

Thank you

Comment: You can write a plugin for that. Or add the shortcode in your theme’s functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the shortcode I'm using for one of my clients:

```
function category_product_count_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts );

    $category = get_term( $atts['id'], 'product_cat' );
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $category->term_id,
            ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $count = $query->post_count;
    
    return $count
    
}
add_shortcode( 'category_product_count', 'category_product_count_shortcode' );
```

The final shortcode to use is this:

```
[category_product_count id="12"]
```

it returns the count of products under a product category. Yu can modify this code according to your needs and your CPT or Taxonomy slug etc.

Comment: Works with id="527" for example, but since I am on an archive page with dynamic content I can't put the ID there and without it, displays 0. Thanks